# Using QRubberBand outside of my program

Tags: c++, qt

I'm using QRubberband and it's working fine inside of my program, but I want to get the coordinates outside of my program. In other words, using it outside of my program while it's running!

To be more clear, I'm using a Qt class called QRubberband which helps you select a rectangle or line "clicking and then drag." Everything is working when I use it inside of my project space, but I can't use it outside - for example when I activate it I should be able to select from maybe this site, or anywhere in the screen not just my program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [QRubberBand man page](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qrubberband.html#details) says:

> If you pass a parent to QRubberBand's constructor, the rubber band
>   will display only inside its parent, but stays on top of other child
>   widgets. If no parent is passed, QRubberBand will act as a top-level
>   widget.

So at the risk of asking the obvious... are you passing in NULL as the second argument to the QRubberBand constructor?

Comment: The problem is even if I did this , yeah I can select outside of my problem but not that well , first the widget needs to be present " showing on the screen " second I can't select anywhere , only on top left area since the button that shows the band is on top left.